# OpenGL ES 2.0 Shader Rotation Per Vertex

Tags: rotation, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

This Question is about Skinning actually.
Lets say we have a model with vertex groups(bones) as a float buffer and we pass it to the shader. is there any way to partial rotate a vertex group? 
buffer is x,y,z,u,v,n1,n2,n3,boneid,rotfactor . (rotfactor is a float that represents the %amount of rotation we want to apply to this vertex). So if rotate the group with a rotation matrix with angle = 45 , is there any way to rotate each vertex for 45 * rotfactor?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This describes in pretty good detail exactly what you're trying to do:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation

Note this line:

```
uniform mat4 Bone[10];  //Array of bones that you compute (animate) on the CPU and you upload to the shader
```

As it implies, you will need to compute a matrix for each bone. You will do this in your application code on the CPU side, i.e. *not* in the shader. You will then pass these matrices in to the uniform variable `Bone`.